# Ignore and override ISP router

Tags: networking, router

I have an ISP router with 10.1.5.x subnet, and I do not have any access to change that to 192.168.1.x

The ISP is not willing to release the admin password, and I am not going to force the issue.

I also need to turn WiFi OFF, the house is crisscrossed with CAT6, there is no need for it. The ISP, again, is unreasonable, and won't do it. The ISP is, by the way called KozarNet up in the North Woods Wisconsin, and it is run by some 16-year old kid who, I was told, "do not give out passwords to customers to THEIR OWN routers in their own basement in an effort to protect inexperienced customers from making a mess".

What should I buy? Any router will do, or I need specific ones with two NICs?

Simply put, I need a home network with WiFi OFF - yes, that KozarNet kid was rolling his eyes as if I was demented even thinking about turning WiFi OFF! So WiFi is STILL ON, because this kid WANTS IT ON. Believe it, I am not making this up.

I also need some static IP for servers, and of course the 192.168.1.x address, since all my notes and scripts are for that address.

So, what should I do? I rather just buy a box than build and configure a server for this, but I am not very familiar with routers for this or for any other purpose.

I am not asking for a specific product recommendation but on advice how to do it. Just buy a box, on one end configure the NIC to the 10.x.x.x, on the other the 192.x.x.x and bridge the two?

The 192.x.x.x end going to use the 10.x.x.x for gateway and for DNS, right?

And all I need to do is hook up a 12-port switch on the 192.x.x.x end to wire the rooms in the house, and start plugging in computers and TVs right?

And I can just ignore what the ISP do as long as they do not chance the 10.x.x.x address, right?

Edit: Up in the Rhinelander WI area you do not yet have choices in ISP,  KozarNet it is - I am glad we have at least them, but they should really be a little more supportive.

Comment: Change ISP? Who owns the line?

Comment: You have every right to know the admin password to the router. If your ISP refuses to give you access to control your own connection, I would in all honesty say switch ISPs to a more reasonable one.

Comment: can you give me the URL of this KozarNet? I'd like to check them out and see what "they" are

Comment: @TD.512 .. http://www.kozartechnologies.com/ - we live in Sugar Camp

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just rung Kozar Technologies, and they said that you can contact them to get your routers admin password and that it's set by the account password. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

**UPDATE**: If that doesn't work and you have ADSL2+ then any ADSL2+ router/modem combo will do fine and you can actually remove the ISP provided router and install your new router

Comment: Thanks, but the router pass is not set by the account pass I can assure you I tried - besides, when you connect to the router via copper it should NOT ask for a login only when you connect through wireless or from a different network, or you want to change something. No, that router is indeed locked from us. - In any case I still want to bypass that router and create a different network.

Comment: I am going to try this, buy and hook up some ADSL2+ modem and see if it allows me to create the 192.x.x.x network. KozarNet had to install some dish on a tree by the garage and route a cable from it to even deliver the internet service, so I am pretty sure it is some more recent technology such as DSL or ADSL

Comment: You usually can't just plug in any old ADSL2+ modem into a DSL line and expect it to work. There are specific values necessary to negotiate with the DSLAM at the other end, specifically the VPI and VCI settings. There is a list of common ISP ones (http://www.speedguide.net/articles/adsl-vpi-vci-and-encapsulation-settings-2786), but for the lesser known ISPs you'll have to call and ask them for their settings. If you're lucky, you can access the values read-only without a password in the current modem (though not all modem models allow this).

Comment: @MaQleod I actually didn't know that, as in NZ all ISPs are so similar that is doesn't matter